# Turning off package-info warning in Checkstyle for Eclipse doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

Even though I disabled the package-info warning, I still get this warning in a jUnit class and another enum class. They are both part of the same project but in different packages, and every other class in either package doesn't pop up this warning anymore.

How can I solve this? I tried turning checkstyle on and off again just to let Eclipse rebuild the project, but it doesn't get fixed.

Comment: Try to right-click your project in Eclipse, and select *Checkstyle → Clear Checkstyle violations*. Then re-run Checkstyle.